# Database - Entry with length of strings - Structure?

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm relaunching a website a found these entries in one of the database tables. I'm wondering what format it is and how i can easily recreate data of a form into this format:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phpwcms_formresult` (
  `formresult_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `formresult_pid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `formresult_createdate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `formresult_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `formresult_content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`formresult_id`),
  KEY `formresult_pid` (`formresult_pid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

One entry looks like this:

```
(3179, 7, '2013-10-02 09:35:48', ':11', 'a:14:{s:13:"veranstaltung";s:4:"name";s:11:"Nick Habbel";s:22:"erziehungsberechtigter";s:12:"Petra Habbel".....;}');
```

In front of every string there is the length of the string "s:22: ...". What kind of format is this?

Any hint is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: see this sqlfiddle I cant see anything wrong with it data is in a bit strange format though http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9846d/1

Comment: Looks like json econding.

Answer (score 0):

An example of this value is done by the [serialization](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) of an array in php:

```
$arr = array("name"=>"Nick Habbel");
echo serialize($arr);

# output:
# a:1:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Nick Habbel";}
```

So, the application that inserts data in your table seems to serialize an array before the insertion. In your example an array (a) with a cardinality of 14 elements (a:14:) plus key/values with lengths and type "s" for strings, "i" for integers etc (s:13:"veranstaltung")